# Counting the quantity of hits to a redirect in the .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, count, http-status-code-301

I've done some research on this and I can't quite find anything conclusive. How do I count the quantity of hits to a redirect that is in the .htaccess file?

I've seen this done in various Wordpress plugins but I can't seem to find any info on hard coding a solution.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to your raw access logs then mining these is usually the simplest method of analysing redirections.